# A bug in System.Json?

Tags: c#, json, mono

Code to reproduce:

```
JsonPrimitive a = new JsonPrimitive("<a href=\"\"/>");
//or the same: JsonPrimitive a = new JsonPrimitive(@"<a href=""/>");
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
//or Console.WriteLine((string)a);
//On the console screen I got:    "<a href=\""/>"
//Ideal:   "<a href=\"\"/>"
```

The version of my System.Json.dll is 2.0.5.0. Is it a bug? And what's the solution?

Aug 2015 UPDATE: It's a bug and already fixed in MONO. Check the link in my answer below.

Comment: You mean you got `<a href=""/>` right?

Comment: @MarcinSeredynski: It's hard to explain. You can run my code and see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's proved to be a bug in the assembly System.Json of [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/). JsonValue.cs line 218 & 219 in the method `string DoEscapeString (StringBuilder sb, string src, int cur)`.

Original:

```
    sb.Append(src[i++]);
    start = i;
```

Fixed:

```
    sb.Append(src[i]);
    start = i + 1;
```

reported to mono team.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `<a href=\"\"/>` as an output, use string parameter for the constructor like this:

```
@"<a href=\""\""/>"
```

or

```
"<a href=\\\"\\\">"
```

and read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=VS.100).aspx